# Multiple TableViews in a Single View Xcode

Tags: ios6

I have one view that has two tableviews, I want one of them to be a twitter feed and the other an RSS feed. The problem is they show up exactly the same, same content. I have tried using another controller, but I cannot do that because i cannot figgure it out.

Comment: Please provide some code so we might understand more about the problem. In particular, the `UITableViewControllerDataSource` methods would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer to your question, but in any case it may be helpful for others too. I have tried the following with success: 
You can use a separate `tableviewcontroller` for each `tableview`. In your `viewDidLoad` you can `alloc init` your tableviewcontrollers and then set the tableview's datasource and delegate to be your respective `tableviewcontrollers`. Finally, set the view of your controllers to be the `tableview` of your `tableview` controller. The following code shows what I mean:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // ...
    if(!self.tweeterTableViewController)
    {
        self.tweeterTableViewController = [[TweeterTableViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if(!self.rssTableViewController)
    {
        self.rssTableViewController = [[RssTableViewController alloc] init];
    }

    [self.tweeterTableView setDataSource:self.tweeterTableViewController];
    [self.tweeterTableView setDelegate:self.tweeterTableViewController];
    self.tweeterTableViewController.view = self.tweeterTableViewController.tableView;

    [self.rssTableView setDataSource:self.rssTableViewController];
    [self.rssTableView setDelegate:self.rssTableViewController];
    self.rssTableViewController.view = self.rssTableViewController.tableView;

    // ...
}
```